# Amplifier impedance compatibility

Tags: amplifier

Amplifier ICs always list the maximum load the amplifier is stable with. For example, a class AB amplifier is listed as 8 ohm capable.

Is that amplifier suitable to drive a 32 ohm load?

Are there any attributes that make an amplifier better suited to drive a lighter load vs a heavier load?

If a similar amplifier is 4 ohm capable, is it less suited to drive a 32 ohm load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really good audio amplifier will have an internal driving impedance very near zero ohms. For light loads, like your 32 ohm example, less audio current is required of the amplifier compared to a load of 8 ohms. That 32 ohm load will receive very close to the same *voltage* as the 8 ohm load. With less current, the 32-ohm speaker will receive less power than the 8 ohm speaker, and all other things being equal, will sound less loud.
The amplifier designer may guarantee that ten watts can be delivered to an 8-ohm load. He/she ensures that enough current can be delivered with low distortion (specified in the spec sheet). That same amplifier cannot deliver ten watts to a 32-ohm speaker - it could easily deliver the (smaller) current, but cannot deliver the larger voltage without distortion - the top and bottom peaks will clip.
Some amplifiers have enough current capability to drive 4-ohm speakers. In many cases, the internal DC supplies that feed the amplifier will sag, so that you don't quite get twice the power compared to a 8-ohm speaker. Such amplifiers will state how much power can be delivered to a 4-ohm load, within a distortion spec. Less-capable amplifiers cannot deliver the current required by a 4-ohm load, and may overheat, blow a fuse, or distort excessively.
**10W into various loads:**
32 ohm 1.58 A (p-p) 50.6 V(p-p)
16 ohm 2.24 A (p-p) 35.8 V(p-p)
8 ohm  3.16 A (p-p) 25.3 V(p-p)
4 ohm  4.47 A (p-p) 17.89 V(p-p)

A class AB amplifier is driven by a DC power supply that is usually designed to output a fixed voltage - enough to deliver the peak-to-peak voltage of a sine wave without clipping. For an 8-ohm speaker, the DC supply would be somewhat higher than 26 volts. If that power supply is "beefy" enough to deliver excess current, and if the amplifier transistors (and heat sink) have excess current capability, then it will likely be able to drive a 4-ohm load, delivering more than ten watts.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of distortion or THD is output current near the limits.

Therefore a higher (32 Ohm) impedance headphone is less likely to be distorted than an 8 Ohm one near max voltage because the current is less. (but obviously less power, of which less is needed for headphones)

However the supply voltage swing available limits the power, so often higher supply voltages tend towards higher impedance output loads to keep the current limitations the same that cause distortion in low power amps.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of distortion of THD is output current near the limits.

Therefore a higher impedance headphone is less likely to be distorted than an 8 Ohm one near max current.

However the supply voltage swing available limits the power, so often higher supply voltages tend towards higher impedance output loads to keep the current limitations the same that cause distortion in low power amps.

You might thing, well if power, P=I^2*R then it is better to use always use more R to get the same power , but then we run out of available voltage or need to boost V or use differential output power amplifiers.